# Bcrypt says data and hash must be a string, passing what I think is strings

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm trying to write login for a small site, this site will never reach production so I'm not too strict on security.

I'm storing data in a MariaDB, cardnumber and pin is some of that data. Cardnumber is encrypted using Bcrypt

But when trying to authenticate I get en error stating

```
[0] (node:9282) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash must be strings
```

I'm console.logging out the data passed to see if it exists, it shows up fine in console. I've also tried to use JSON.stringify for the data retrived from the front end.

The code in my authenticator file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../models/loginrouters');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Starting authentification proccess');
  const CardNumber = req.body.cardnumber;
  const pin = JSON.stringify(req.body.pin);
  connection.query(
    'SELECT PIN, CardNumber FROM userCards WHERE CardNumber = ?',
    [CardNumber],
    function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error ocurred', error);
        res.send({
          code: 400,
          failed: 'error ocurred'
        });
      } else {
        console.log('The result is: ', results);
        console.log('handling pin', pin);
        if (results.length > 0) {
          console.log('results over 0 is true');
          console.log('pin result from query is: ', results[0].PIN);
          console.log('pin result from form is: ', pin);
          if (bcrypt.compare(pin, 15) == results[0].PIN) {
            res.send({
              code: 200,
              success: 'login sucessfull'
            });
          } else {
            console.log('something went wrong/email and password does not match');
            res.send({
              code: 204,
              success: 'Email and password does not match'
            });
          }
        } else {
          console.log('result lenght is 0');
          res.send({
            code: 204,
            success: 'Email does not exits'
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've also tried hardcoding the data (pin and results[0].PIN) but get the same error, full console output of the error can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/x0cE5y9J)

Any ideas on where the error is? I'd be happy to post more code if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this isue, not quite sure how but I re-wrote the code and tried following the bcrypt documentation as closely as possible, here is the working code.

```
router.post('/', function(req, result) {
  console.log('Starting authentification proccess');
  const CardNumber = req.body.cardnumber;
  const pin = req.body.pin;
  connection.query(
    'SELECT PIN, CardNumber FROM userCards WHERE CardNumber = ?',
    [CardNumber],
    function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error ocurred', error);
        res.send({
          code: 400,
          failed: 'error ocurred'
        });
      } else {
        console.log('The result is: ', results);
        console.log('handling pin', pin);
        if (results.length > 0) {
          console.log('results over 0 is true');
          console.log('pin result from query is: ', results[0].PIN);
          console.log('pin result from form is: ', pin);

          bcrypt.compare(pin, results[0].PIN, function(err, res) {
            if (res) {
              console.log('login succefull');
              result.send({
                code: 200,
                success: 'login sucessfull'
              });
            } else if (err) {
              console.log('something went wrong/email and password does not match');
              console.log(err);
              result.send({
                code: 204,
                success: err
              });
            } else {
              console.log('result lenght is 0');
              result.send({
                code: 204,
                success: 'Email does not exits'
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to change the datatype of the password field in the database to char (150).

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this issue you have to parse the Candidate Password(Password taken through login form) and real Password that store in database to String.

For example:

```
bcrypt.compare(JSON.stringify(candidatePassword), JSON.stringify(userPassword))
```